# Showing a forest with root of the trees on the top

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a Graph object that contains a forest with directed trees. I want to draw the forest such that the root of the trees are on the top and the leaves are on the bottom. If I use the following line of code:

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
  2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
  7 \[DirectedEdge] 4}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing"]
```

I get this image:

[image: forest]

Everything looks fine except the root (#3) is not on top. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: I changed the `graph style` to `basic black` from the context menu. I don't think it changes the semantic that I want to express.

Comment: In your rules 7 connects to 6. In your picture 7 connects to 4.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: Thank you. I fixed the issue. I hope everything is fine now.

Comment: In version 9 there's also the `"RootVertex"` suboption of GraphLayout, which might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6, 7 -> 4}, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

This may not be the best way to do this but this is one way to do it: introduce single nodes by just connecting it to itself and shade the edge white. Also `EdgeRenderingFunction` and `VertexRenderingFunction` allow you to play with your `LayeredGraphPlot`. There is also `VertexCoordinateRules` that enables you to place your vertices wherever you like.

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6, 7 -> 4,9 -> 9}, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True, VertexRenderingFunction -> ({White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#, .1], 
 Black, Text[#2, #1]} &), EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[Intersection[{{9, 9}}, {#2}] != {}, {White, Line[#1]}, If[Intersection[{{1, 2}, {4, 6}}, {#2}] != {}, {Blue,       Arrow[#1]}, {Red, Line[#1]}]] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amatya. "Bottom" is the keyword that I was looking for. What if I want to show some additional nodes without edges? And how about path highlighting? With a Graph I can easily do all of those things.

Comment: @Mohsen I edited the answer to address your concerns.

Comment: I found the you can pass `Graph` objects to `LayeredGraphPlot` as well. So, this does the trick for the my first concern: `LayeredGraphPlot[
 Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
   7 \[DirectedEdge] 6}], Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True]`

Comment: @Mohsen oh cool. I didn't know one could do that! Thx!

Answer (score 3):

In version 9, one can use the new built in layout version of `Graph` for trees: `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"`.

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6, 7 -> 4},
    VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 200, ImagePadding -> 10,
    GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom}]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be with determining the root vertex of the tree.  The reason why using an embedding designed for directed graphs seems to fix the problem is that the directedness makes it clearer which node should be considered the root.  But Mathematica seems to consider the root to have outgoing edges, not incoming ones.  So here the root is really `1` and not `3`, it's just that the whole layout is turned upside down.  This observation becomes important when starting to play with the `"RootVertex"` suboption of `GraphLayout`: specifying a node with only incoming edges ...

Comment: ... as the root will confuse Mathematica because otherwise it still wants to layout the graph so that the arrows point towards "lower levels" ("lower" meaning further from the root).  Try this: `Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 ImagePadding -> 10, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom, 
   "RootVertex" -> 3}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Furthermore (or "something completely different"): `Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]` draws an undirected graph. So I guess `LayeredDigraphEmbedding` is only reliable in the simplest cases.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that it isn't possible to determine the root vertices.  You would need to specify them somehow.

Generally, if you use `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` on a directed graph, it takes vertices with only outgoing connections as the roots.  However, the first component of your graph wouldn't be a tree with that interpretation.  It seems to me that you want exactly the opposite, i.e. you want to use `6` and `3` as the roots (vertices with only incoming connections).  This is not entirely clear from the description though.

Both `"LayeredEmbedding"` and `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` allow specifying a single root vertex (e.g. `GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> 3}`). However, I could not find a built-in way to specify multiple roots for a forest.

[The IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) does have a tree layout function that allows specifying root vertices for each component in a forest graph:

```
IGLayoutReingoldTilford[g, "RootVertices" -> {6, 3}]
```

[image]

By default, roots are on the top, but you can also use different orientations:

```
IGLayoutReingoldTilford[g, "RootVertices" -> {6, 3}, "Rotation" -> Pi/2]
```

[image]