# Transition between graphs

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, visualization

I want to visually demonstrate the manipulations made to a graph. For instance, I have a graph `g` where using the command `LayeredGraphPlot[g, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True]` I get this figure as the output:

[image: g1]

After adding an edge and using the same command I get this one:

[image: g2]

I want to show a smooth transition between the two figures so that the user can track the addition of the edge. Is there any easy/general way to do such an effect in Mathematica.

Comment: If you place your graphs in a list then you can use `ListAnimate`.

Comment: I only have two graphs. Does it interpolate between the graphs? I mean, does it make the frames in between the two graphs or I need to make the middle frames by hand?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "smooth" 2 graphs might not be enough. In this case you have to make the intermediate frames "by hand".

Comment: So, how can I find the vertex positions in the graphs? If it was a `Graph` object, I could do it easily, but `LayeredGraphPlot` returns a `Graphics` object rather than a `Graph`!

Comment: You can use `HighlightGraph` together with Manipulate or (as b.gatessucks mentioned) ListAnimate.

Comment: I have no idea how I can use `HighlightGraph` to move the vertices. But I guess I know how to do it using `ListAnimate`. The only issue is that I cannot find the vertex positions in the `Graphics` object. If I could, the rest looks straightforward.

Comment: To get the VertexCoordinates of g, with 7 vertices: `PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ Range[7]`

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Thanks, `ListAnimate` did the trick.

Comment: @Mohsen Thanks for posting the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While David's answer is a nice one, it's not actually what I am looking for. As I commented on his answer, I am looking for an answer that:

1. Handles dynamic user inputs, so a fixed final graph does not do the job. You can consider a compelete graph as the final graph, but I don't think this is a good idea.
2. I need to use `LayeredGraphPlot` to place the vertices correctly.

Based on these requirements, I found this answer:

```
g1 = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
    2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
    7 \[DirectedEdge] 6}];
g2 = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
    2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
    7 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 3}];

AnimateGraphs[g1_, g2_] := Module[
   {
    gr1 = LayeredGraphPlot[g1, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True],
    gr2 = LayeredGraphPlot[g2, Bottom, VertexLabeling -> True],
    coord1, coord2, delta, fps = 30
    },
   coord1 = Last[Last[gr1[[1]]]];
   coord2 = Last[Last[gr2[[1]]]];
   delta = coord2 - coord1;
   Table[GraphPlot[g1, VertexLabeling -> True, 
      VertexCoordinateRules -> (coord1 + (i - 1)/fps delta)], {i, 1, 
      fps}]~Append~gr2
   ];
ListAnimate[AnimateGraphs[g1, g2], AppearanceElements -> None, 
 DefaultDuration -> 0.5, AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

It uses `Last[Last[gr1[[1]]]]` to find the vertex coordinates that I think is not a robust way. Please comment if you have a better solution. The rest is simple.

Answer (score 7):

**To get the vertex coordinates** for graph g, defined below:

```
PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ Range[7]
```

e.g.

> {{2.32379, 0.}, {2.32379, 0.774597}, {1.54919, 1.54919}, {1.54919, 
>     0.}, {0.774597, 0.}, {0.774597, 0.774597}, {0., 0.}}

---

**To Animate, without moving vertices....**

Here's a rough overview of how you might approach the problem using highlights. You don't need to move the vertices. You can simply fill in the graph step by step. We'll build the graph in three steps and then play it backwards. You can add the highlights and additional steps that suit you.

**Begin** by making the graph you want to **end** with:

```
edges = {DirectedEdge[7, 6], DirectedEdge[5, 6], DirectedEdge[4, 6], DirectedEdge[6, 3], DirectedEdge[2, 3], DirectedEdge[1, 2]};
g = Graph[edges, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing" ]
```

[image: final graph]

---

**Next**, make the next to final drawing of the graph:

```
g1 = Graph[edges, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing", 
GraphHighlight -> Join[{3, 6}, {DirectedEdge[6, 3]}], 
GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightFade" ]
```

### [image: penultimate]

Now let's jump to the first step, where there are two connected components. They need to be in the proper place so they won't have to move later.

```
g2 = Graph[edges, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", GraphLayout -> "LayeredDrawing", 
GraphHighlight -> Join[Range[7], Complement[edges, {DirectedEdge[6, 3]}]], 
GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide" ]
```

Setting the `GraphHighlightStyle` to `DehighlightHide` allows you to hide parts of the graph (the edge from vertex 6 to vertex 3).

[image: first graph]

---

In the animation you will want to display them in reverse order:

[image: graphics grid]

---

Here's the `ListAnimate` code for showing the three frames we made:

```
ListAnimate[{g2, g1, g}]
```

[image: list animate]

---

With additional frames you could assemble the graph, vertex by vertex, edge by edge, using the highlights of your choosing.

Comment: I cannon see any animation in your code.

Comment: Hold on, I'm getting to that part

Comment: Sure ....... :)

Comment: Why is there a downvote for this answer?

Comment: @Lou: Downvote was mine. David posted an incomplete/not-functional answer at the beginning, but he completed it later. I just +1ed it.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: This is a nice answer, but not what I am looking for. There are two issues: 1. I don't know the final graph from the beginning, that's because I am making it in an interactive manner and based on the user's input, I may get a different final answer. 2. I need to use `LayeredGraphPlot` to place the vertices correctly. See my other question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11823/showing-a-forest-with-root-of-the-trees-on-the-top . `LayeredGraphPlot` returns a graphics object, not a graph, so I cannot use your method to get the vertex positions.